# 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 th fibonacci number

Tags: fibonacci

The problem is Get Under 1,000,000,000,000,000,000th fibonacci number%1,000,000

```
#include <iostream>
#define fibo(a,b) {long long c=b;b=a;a=(b+c)%1000000;}

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long a=1,b=0;     //two num
    long long pa,pb,n,k,arr[2][1000];   //last two num,input,input<=2^k
    cin>>n;
    arr[0][0]=n/2;arr[1][0]=n%2;
    for(unsigned long long i=1;n>3;i++){
        arr[0][i]=arr[0][i-1]/2;
        arr[1][i]=arr[0][i-1]%2;
        if(arr[0][i]==1){
            k=i;

            break;
        }
    }
    if(n<=3){      //special occasions
        switch(n){
            case 0:cout<<"0"<<endl;break;
            case 3:cout<<"2"<<endl;break;
            default:cout<<"1"<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    while(k>=0){   //calc
        pa=a;pb=b;
        a=((pa+pb*2)*pa)%1000000;     //F(2n)=(F(n)+F(n-1)*2)*F(n)
        b=(pa*pa+pb*pb)%1000000;      //F(2n-1)=F(n)^2+F(n-1)^2
        if(arr[1][k--]==1){fibo(a,b);}   //F(n+1)=F(n)+F(n-1)

    }
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when is it wrong?
And why is it wrong?
I can't find different occasion.

Comment: There is a [closed form equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) for the nth Fibonacci number - there is no need to calculate them all.

Comment: Thanks to answer but I need integer number, not float

Comment: This is a formula for the nth Fibonacci number, an integer by very definition. I have absolutely no idea what your comment means.

Comment: The problem site needs the accurate value. So I need integer number

Comment: The formula gives an **exact** value. It is a closed for equation **not** an approximation. You seem to misunderstand what "closed form equation" means. And you also seem to be confused by the usage of irrational numbers in the formula - given infinite precision the formula will provide an integer answer. Obviously if you approximate the irrational numbers in decimal form, you will get an approximation as a result of the formula - but that's a simple enough problem to solve.

Comment: @stoad: The formula gives you an integer number and NOT a float. If your implementation of it yields a float, round it to the next integer.

Comment: The Binet formula involves taking huge powers of floats and will lead to errors for large values like the one in the OP. No serious student of Fibonacci uses the Binet formula: not for calculating by hand, not for calculating with a computer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach you could consider using here is the fact that there are only 1,000,000 possible remainders for Fibonacci numbers, so if you were to compute the first 1,000,001 Fibonacci numbers, at some point you would find that the numbers would start to go in a cycle. So consider the following approach:

- Compute the first 1,000,001 Fibonacci numbers.
- The numbers will eventually enter a cycle. Determine how many steps k are needed to enter the cycle and how long l the cycle is.
- The 1,000,000,000,000,000,000th Fibonacci number, mod 1,000,000, can be found by determining what position the 1,000,000,000,000,000,000th Fibonacci number would end up in the cycle, which is the  ((1,000,000,000,000,000,000 - k) % l)th position. So look at that position and output the entry there.